# ARC Leaking Function

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Converted a project to ARC and in the Leak Instrument this function is repeatedly tagged as a leak.

I was thinking that objc_release maybe a solution but xCode doesn't like that.

```
- (int)getNumber{
int result = 0;



unsigned char *myBytes = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
[stream getBytes:myBytes range:NSMakeRange(0, sizeof(char))];

char tag = myBytes[0];

if((int)tag >= 0 ){

    result = (int)tag - 64;
}
else if ((int)tag == -64 ) {

    [self removeChar];

    result = [self getInt];


}
else 
{

    [self removeChar];
    unsigned char *byteTwo = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    [stream getBytes:byteTwo range:NSMakeRange(0, sizeof(char))];
    char twoTag = byteTwo[0];

    result = 
    ((((int)tag & 0x03f) << 8) |
     (twoTag & 0x0ff)) ; 
    result -= 8192;

}

return result;
```

}

The two functions called within the function are

```
- (void)removeChar{
[stream replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withBytes:NULL length:0];
```

}

and

```
- (int)getInt{
NSRange intRange = NSMakeRange(0,3);

char buffer[4];
[stream getBytes:buffer length:4];

[stream replaceBytesInRange:intRange withBytes:NULL length:0];


return (int) (
              (((int)buffer[0] & 0xff) << 24) |
              (((int)buffer[1] & 0xff) << 16) |
              (((int)buffer[2] & 0xff) << 8) |
              ((int)buffer[3] & 0xff) );
```

}

Comment: `malloc` without `free`? That does look like a leak... But maybe there's something else going on that I'm not understanding. What does the Static Analyzer say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ever getting rid of myBytes and byteTwo?  It is my understanding that Arc doesn't handle memory management at that level?

[LLVM Arc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general)

Comment: Yup, ARC does not mess with `malloc()`, only objects.

Comment: Thanks teamaxe - free(myBytes) and  free (byteTwo) cleaned everything up.  No more leaks!